# stuck to find logic of this program

Tags: logic

**Example 1:**

- input
- arr1 = [2, 6, 8];
- arr2 = [4, 3, 4, 4];
- **output = [4, 6, 1, 2];**

**Example 2:**

- input
- arr1 = [20, 16, 33, 11];
- arr2 = [5, -7, 6];
- **output = [2, 2, 3, 7, 7];**

Comment: what's the full problem statement ? it seems a bit weird for a logical ability question !

Answer (score 0):

### Finally I find the logic it's simple addition that's it.

Taking the two arrays and add it that will the third array

4344(+)268=4612